# How to call struct data members?

Tags: c#, struct

In C++ you can call the struct data members like this, how can I do this in C#? I know how to make the struct and assign the data members value, but I'm having trouble calling them.

```
struct stuctName
{
      char dataMemberOne;
      char dataMemberTwo;
}

int main ()
{
      structName structOne, structTwo;

      cout << structOne.dataMemberOne << endl; //assuming it has a value 
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use msdn for such questions.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taef578.aspx

Comment: Please rephrase your question. A C++ example has nothing to do with the issue, the only thing relevant is your first two lines: too few and a reason to close. Edit your post with the relevant C# code.

Comment: I don't know the relevant C# code, that's why I was asking.The person below seemed to understand it well enough.

Comment: Don't use StackOverflow as a substitute for a tutorial. We're here to answer concrete questions, not teach you a certain aspect of the language.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I didn't realize you were the creator of StackOverflow and got to decide what the use was for because the about page says it's for answering "every question about programming". Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new instance of the struct and assign values to the fields before using it.

```
struct stuctName
{
      public char dataMemberOne;
      public char dataMemberTwo;
}

static void Main()
{
    structName structOne = new structName();
    structName structTwo = new structName();

    structOne.dataMemberOne = 'a'; //aassign a value

    Console.WriteLine(structOne.dataMemberOne);  // will output 'a'

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if your answer is in c# please change `main to `Main`

Comment: I was simply copying the OP's code, but it's a reasonable update :)

Answer (score 1):

It should work just by calling `structVar.memberName`, note that in C# struct members default to `private` visibility, so they have to made `public` explicitly.